# como hacer una validación condicional de un campo de un formulario reactivo en angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Estoy creando un formulario en angular. Tengo por un lado en una ruta el cuestionario con los datos de una persona y en otra que me liste todos los datos introducidos de todas las personas guardadas.
Sobre esa lista de personas necesito implementar que se pueda modificar cualquier campo, por lo que genere un nuevo cuestionario en el que pregunto qué campo quieres modificar (*Tipo*) y el dato a introducir (*datoInsertar*).
El problema viene cuando quiero validar ese dato con los validadores.
Hice uno personalizado para decirle si el campo es nombre aplica tal validación, si es edad aplica tal otra. El problema es que siempre me dice que el campo *tipo* es `undefined` aunque si lo saco de dentro de la función sí que esta definido.

Pego aquí el constructor y la función para ver si alguien sabe cómo acceder a la variable para poder validar:

```
import { Component, OnInit, } from '@angular/core';
import { ContactoService } from '../contacto.service';
import { Usuario } from '../modelos/empleado.modelo';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators,AbstractControl, ValidatorFn, Validator, NG_VALIDATORS } from '@angular/forms';

export class AgendaComponent implements OnInit {

    agenda: Array<Usuario> = []
    posicionActualizar: any;
    modificacion: boolean = false;
    formTipo: FormGroup;
    formDato: FormGroup;
    valorTipo:any = ""
    
    // validacion: any = "nombre";
    constructor(
      private contactoService: ContactoService
    ) {
      this.formTipo = new FormGroup({
        tipo: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
        
      })
      this.formDato = new FormGroup({
       
        datoInsertar: new FormControl('', [ Validators.required,this.validatorsFactory ])
      })
    }

    validatorsFactory() {
    
    if (this.valorTipo == 'nombre') {
      return (control: AbstractControl) => {
        if(control.value >= 3) return null
        return { valido: 'el campo debe tener 3 caracteres' }
      }
    }
    
    return () => null
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

El error se produce porque la función `valido()` tiene referencia a la propiedad `valorTipo` la cual existe en el objeto `AgendaComponent`. Cuando `valido()` se pasa al arreglo de validadores cambia su contexto y `this` ya no hace referencia a `AgendaComponent` por lo tanto `valorTipo` no existe.

Eso se puede solucionar usando una función que sirva de fábrica de validadores:

```
validatorsFactory() {
    
    if (this.valorTipo == 'nombre') {
      return (control: AbstractControl) => {
        if(control.value >= 3) return null
        return { valido: 'el campo debe tener 3 caracteres' }
      }
    }
    
    return () => null
  }
```

Observa como la función que sirve de fábrica sí tiene acceso a `valorTipo`, eso es porque esa función se ejecutará en el contexto de `AgendaComponent` y devolverá un validador independiente del contexto.

Luego esa función se usa así:

```
datoInsertar: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, this.validatorsFactory()])
```

[Angular custom validators](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#defining-custom-validators)

Comment: Antetodo muchas gracias importe import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators,AbstractControl, ValidatorFn, Validator, NG_VALIDATORS } from '@angular/forms'; para definir control: AbstractControl pero sigue diciendo core.js:6210 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'valorTipo' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'valorTipo' of undefined que puedo hacer?

Comment: Agrega el código actualizado a la pregunta.

Comment: lo modifique arriba

Comment: Es que no estás usando la función nueva `validatorsFactory` revisa el ejemplo de cómo se usa.

Comment: aquí estaba mal puesto lo de this.validatorsFactory pero en el código no y sigue dando error , te referías a eso o sigo mirando

Comment: Es así: `[Validators.required, this.validatorsFactory()]` fíjate que no se pasa la función `this.validatorsFactory` sino que lo que devuelve al ejecutarla, por eso tiene los paréntesis al final.

Comment: perfecto ahora si, disculpa no me di cuenta que faltaba el parentesis de la funcion